# Create new column derived from current columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

The question is: how to create a new column in Postgres SQL based on existing columns.

A work around was to create of a unique row identifier and create a parallel table with the row identifier, compute the desired update, and then replace `row_3` with the update based on the unique row identifier. This is manual and not very efficient.

Assume the table structure is:

```
create table tab (
  row_1 integer
, row_2 integer
, row_3 integer);
```

Assume the table has 1000 entries and `row_1` and `row_2` have legitimate values.

The question is: How can `row_3` be updated to reflect the sum of `row_1` and `row_2` for the entire table. This should work for an arbitrary table.

Comment: You're probably better off with a view rather than adding a calculated column

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "new" column to be up-to-date, then I would recommend using a view:

```
create view v_tab as
    select tab.*, (col1 + col2) as col3
    from tabl;
```

(I experience cognitive dissonance when columns are referred to as "row". ;)

This will do the calculation when the table is queried, so the results are always consistent.

If you just want a one-time change to the values, then use `update`.

Comment: Is there the concept of a pointer? The question was simplified and unfortunately that dodged the point.

Comment: @DanSawyer: It may have dodged your (undisclosed) point, but it's the best answer to the question asked. It's a bad idea to store functionally dependent values redundantly, even more so, when calculated so easily. Calculating on the fly will typically be *faster* (besides being more reliable) than the possibly added disk I/O from redundant storage. I suggest you start a new question where you ask what you actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMN row_3 INTEGER;

UPDATE tab SET row_3 = row_1+row_2;
```

If you want a 'NOT NULL' constraint on column 'row_3' then add it after the UPDATE.